# зачем атрибуты в AST?

Tags: парсер, синтаксический-анализ

с какими целями в абстрактных синтаксических деревьях размечают узлы атрибутами?

это делают из-за того, что создают обобщенные объекты узлов, а не объекты отдельных строго-типизированных классов? Или использование атрибутов позволяет как-то удобнее писать обобщённые алгоритмы с узлами дерева основываясь на значениях атрибутов? Или переменные-члены классов-узлов дерева разбора как раз и являются этими самыми атрибутами, просто это другая терминология?

В общем, что надо прочитать (электронное, доступное в интернете, даром), чтобы наступила ясность?

Comment: Очень вероятно, что это просто терминология, приведите конкретный пример.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_grammar